# Getting started with Hubot

Tags: node.js, macos, coffeescript, npm, hubot

I just pulled [hubot](https://hubot.github.com/) down from github.  I ran `npm install` from `\d\projects\hubot` and got pounded with errors.  The first error may be causing the rest:

> d:\projects\hubot\node_modules\hubot-hipchat\node_modules\node-xmpp\node_modules\node-xmpp-core\node_modules\node-stringprep>node
>   "d:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp->  bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   rebuild gyp ERR! configure error gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed:
>   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler
>   (child_process.js:647:15) gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit
>   (events.js:98:17) gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose
>   (child_process.js:755:16) gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.
>   (child_process.js:968:11) gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit
>   (events.js:95:17) gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12) gyp
>   ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601 gyp ERR! command "node" "d:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   "rebuild" gyp ERR! cwd
>   d:\projects\hubot\node_modules\hubot-hipchat\node_modules\node-xmpp\node_modules\node-xmpp-core\node_modules\node-stringprep
>   gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.29 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.1 gyp ERR! not ok

The first line is pointing to a folder that does not exist on my machine:

`d:\projects\hubot\node_modules\hubot-hipchat\node_modules\node-xmpp\node_modules\node-xmpp-core`

node-xmpp-core does not exist.  I tried installing `node-xmpp-client` and `node-xmpp-sever` and once again...tons of errors.

Any idea how I can get to the bottom of this mess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I started with the wrong command.

**Mac Setup**

After pulling down the repo, the right command to start with is:

`sudo npm install -g yo generator-hubot`

Other stuff you need:

- [node.js](http://nodejs.org/download/)
- [npm](https://npmjs.org/)
- [Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/) : sudo npm install -g coffee-script
- [Redis](http://redis.io/)

This is where things get tricky.

- mkdir myhubot
- cd myhubot
- yo hubot --owner="Bot Wrangler " --name="Hubot" --description="Delightfully aware robutt" --adapter=campfire --defaults

(yo hubot command installs hubot!)

Now **switch back to the root directory** \wherever\hubot

- npm install (install all the other bits hubot also needs)

**switch back to the created directory** \wherever\hubot\myhubot

- Execute hubot :- `bin/hubot` (installs npm dependencies, loads scripts, launches hubot)

***This will put you at a prompt and there will be a bunch of garbage on the screen.  Hit `<enter>`.***  Now you get the correct prompt...

`Hubot>` and you can type "hubot help" to test him out.

If hubot does not respond to commands check to make sure you ran `bin/hubot` from the directory you created `\wherever\hubot\myhubot`.  You can run `bin/hubot` from the root, but the prompt won't respond to commands.

[Full instructions](https://github.com/github/hubot/blob/master/docs/README.md) for setup were found on github.

**Windows Setup**

Basically the same thing.  Don't use sudo before any of the commands listed above.  You also need two additional packages before Hubot will run.  I recommend installing these first:

1. Install Python 3.2:  https://www.python.org/download/releases/3.2/
2. Install LMXL :        https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.4.2 (the one related to Python 3.2)

[Write some scripts](https://github.com/github/hubot/blob/master/docs/scripting.md) to make him do interesting things.

- `\wherever\hubot\myhubot\scripts\example.coffee` is a good place to start

Comment: "yo hubot --owner="Bot Wrangler " --name="Hubot" --description="Delightfully aware robutt" --adapter=campfire --defaults" You don't have to use this command. You can also just run "yo hubot" and the generator will ask you all these things. Running it this way is more user friendly since you don't have to remember all these options.